css and js files are not loading in laravel project loacally,
error shown in networkcss and js is not loading on http and https, path provided is also correct,css and js files also exist in public folder
I tried to run on both http and https but it's not working
i am trying to load the css and js for laravel-9 project
what is the solution for this?

You've not provided enough detail to debug the problem. Your first step should be to open browser devtools (press F12) and check the network tab to see if the file URLs are valid and that they are being loaded correctly. Then check for errors in the console.

the request url is
https://localhost/frontend/css/bootstrap.css  and getting the 404 error for the bootstrap.css file. but css file is exist at the mentioned path

I'm getting this error in console
GET https://localhost/frontend/css/bootstrap.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
